# Understanding of remote EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am playing around with JBoss and EJB, I use [jboss-eap-quickstarts](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/7.1.x-develop/ejb-remote)

I have `server-side` class:

```
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.stateless;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@Remote(RemoteCalculator.class)
public class CalculatorBean implements RemoteCalculator {

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    @Override
    public int subtract(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

And I have `client-side` method:

```
private static RemoteCalculator lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator() throws NamingException {
    final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    return (RemoteCalculator) context.lookup(
     "ejb:/jboss-as-ejb-remote-server-side/CalculatorBean!" + RemoteCalculator.class.getName()
  );
}
```

The **questions** are:

1. What have been deployed to server? `Class` / `Object` / both? How
   did client find classes/objects?
2. How did `ejb:/jboss-as-ejb-remote-server-side/CalculatorBean!" +
   RemoteCalculator.class.getName()` help hence it doesn't know
   `host:port`?
3. Where was executed `CalculatorBean` logic on the `server` or
   `client` side? Again if it was executed at the `Server`, how did
   exchange of values between two `jvm`s worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The client finds the classes/objects because the client have dependencies to the interfaces of the server-side (`pom.xml` file).
2. It finds the host:port thanks to the file `jboss-eap-quickstarts/ejb-remote/client/src/main/resources/jboss-ejb-client.properties`
   *Note that you can configure your server to expose your services on a different port*.
3. `CalculatorBean` logic will be executed on the server side.

For all questions that i've not answered, (What's deployed where, exchange of values between jvm and how the JNDI address (`ejb:/ ...`) allow the client to find the correct service), you should read about how JNDI and EJBs work.

Here is a good start :

JNDI:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076888/core-java/jndi-overview--part-1--an-introduction-to-naming-services.html

EJBs:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071724/java-web-development/ejb-fundamentals-and-session-beans.html

Answer (score 3):

EJBs are based on the concept of [RMI (remote method invocation) over IIOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI-IIOP) that helps bring [corba](/questions/tagged/corba) into the java world.

On the server side, there are three parts:

1. EJB implementation - concrete class containing implementation methods.
2. Home Interface - interface extending `javax.ejb.EJBHome` that must contain a `create()` method. Used by client code to create a bean instance.
3. Remote Interface - interface extending `javax.ejb.EJBObject` that declares all methods that you'd wish your client code should be able to access.

On the client side, you must first `lookup` the ejb. This is where JNDI comes in picture. There is no need of `host:port` because you have to register the bean in the Java Naming Directory on the server side. This registry is made with a name (represented by `ejb:/jboss-as-ejb-remote-server-side/CalculatorBean!" + RemoteCalculator.class.getName()` ) in your case.

This is published by the server and the client uses it to access the Home interface. This in turn gives you access to all the implemented methods in the bean, that are declared in the remote interface.

Hope this addresses your three questions.